# How to shorten code in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can someone please help me shorten this? This is the best I can do and its working but its slow! And it does not look good. Im a beginner so I know the code is not great but its best I can do.

```
$('.classical-a-btn').click(function() {
    $('.classical-a').show();
    $('.classical-b').hide();
    $('.classical-c').hide();
    $('.classical-d').hide();
    $('.classical-e').hide();
    $('.classical-f').hide();
    $('.classical-g').hide();
    $('.classical-h').hide();
    $('.classical-i').hide();
});
 $('.classical-b-btn').click(function() {
    $('.classical-b').show();
    $('.classical-a').hide();
    $('.classical-c').hide();
    $('.classical-d').hide();
    $('.classical-e').hide();
    $('.classical-f').hide();
    $('.classical-g').hide();
    $('.classical-h').hide();
    $('.classical-i').hide();
});
 $('.classical-c-btn').click(function() {
    $('.classical-c').show();
    $('.classical-b').hide();
    $('.classical-a').hide();
    $('.classical-d').hide();
    $('.classical-e').hide();
    $('.classical-f').hide();
    $('.classical-g').hide();
    $('.classical-h').hide();
    $('.classical-i').hide();
});
```

Comment: Let me know if your still facing trouble so I can help

Answer (score 6):

Use the [**attribute starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('.classical-a-btn').click(function() {
    $('[class^="classical"]').hide();
    $('.classical-a').show();
});
 $('.classical-b-btn').click(function() {
    $('[class^="classical"]').hide();
    $('.classical-b').show();
});
 $('.classical-c-btn').click(function() {
    $('[class^="classical"]').hide();
    $('.classical-c').show();
});
```

If you can modify the HTML of the buttons like

```
 <button class="classical-a-btn" data-letter="a"></button>
```

you can shorten it **even** further to one handler like

```
 $('[data-letter]').click(function() {
        $('[class^="classical"]').hide();
        $('.classical-'+$(this).attr('data-letter')).show();
    });
```

Comment: Note that this might affect other classes. If you for example have an element with the class `classicalmusic`, that will be hidden too.

Comment: @Guffa, yes good point. In that case the OP would have to explictly mention the class names(like in your answer) and avoid using `^=`

Comment: @BhushanFirake, dont forget to mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer(the answer **you** feel was the most beneficial)

Comment: @AmmarCSE I haven't asked the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that hides all those elements and shows one specific element. Then call the function with a parameter that determines which element to show:

```
function show(className) {
  $('.classical-a,.classical-b,.classical-c,.classical-d,.classical-e,.classical-f,.classical-g,.classical-h,.classical-i').hide();
  $(className).show();
}

$('.classical-a-btn').click(function() {
    show('.classical-a');
});
 $('.classical-b-btn').click(function() {
    show('.classical-b');
});
 $('.classical-c-btn').click(function() {
    show('.classical-c');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider seperating your concerns a bit, and adding another class to your "classical-" elements.

By this I mean adding classes to everything you touch in your javascript, perhaps like: `js-classical-hideable` and then using this in your javascript only (not css), like so:

```
$('.classical-a-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.js-classical-hideable').hide();
    $('.classical-a').show();
});
```

You could then take it a step further and do it for your buttons with `js-classical-btn`:

```
$('.js-classical-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.js-classical-hideable').hide();
    $('.classical-a').hide();
});
```

You could even put your target as a data-attribute to seperate the target element by javascript and css:

```
<button type='button' class='classical-btn js-classical-btn' data-target='js-classical-a'> Show A </button>
```

An example of a target element would then be:

```
<div class='classical js-classical-hideable js-classical-a'> content </div>
```

(Of course if you're absolutely 100% sure there'll only be one of each I'd probably put the identifier as an id)

```
<div id='js-classical-a' class='classical js-classical-hideable'> content </div>
```

Where the class `classical` is used for css only, and the class `js-classical-a` for a target in your javascript only.

Which means you could then (after putting id `js-classical-a` on the target you want to show on click):

```
$('.js-classical-btn').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('.js-classical-hideable').hide();
    $('#' + target).show();
});
```

Now you wouldn't have to worry about someone changing the class you're using in javascript to match another css rule or something similar.

Just one of many approaches!

EDIT: You probably want to use jQuery's 'on' as well: http://api.jquery.com/on/